# rewriting htaccess for a specific url and redirect to 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site uses rewrites and urls such as this one:

http://example.com/profile/199801173

However, when someone does something like:

http://example.com/profile/199801173kjsjsk

It still redirects to the page of the prior link.

How can I fix this rewrite rule and make it go to a 404 page instead of going to the profile page?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

my profile url was in query string i rewrite it via htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Kindly help me how i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression simply looks for any string that doesn't include a `/`.

- The `[^/]` segment means "anything that's not a `/`"
- The `*` following that means "look for 0 or more of the preceeding"
- The final `$` means "end of string")

Put together, that's "look 0 or more of any character except `/`, followed by an end of string". From the example you posted, it looks like you only want to check for an arbitrary number of digits. You can achieve that as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This means "look for any number of digits between 0 and 9, followed by an end of string".

---

*EDIT:* Based on the comments, it looks like you want to restrict to a specific number of digits. As described above, the `*` means "any number". You can replace that with `{n}` for just `n` digits, or `{m,n}` for between `m` and `n` digits, inclusive. E.g., for seven digits:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]{7})$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: when i enter alphabets in front of it work gud but when i enter integer it giving same error redirect to my profile page

Comment: http://example.com/profile/19980117377737 here it give error mean redirect to my profile page                                                                         but  http://example.com/profile/199801173ksjdkdd here it work gud

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - I don't understand what you're asking. The rewrite rule simply takes the provided URL and rewrites it to a different pattern. Your first example is identical to `/profile.php?user=19980117377737`, and your second to `/profile.php?user=199801173ksjdkdd`. The redirect just rewrites the URL from the first pattern (`^profile/(...`) to the second (`/profile.php?...`). Are you asking how to institute error checking in the php page itself?

Comment: It work good for integer how i restrict it on specific length

Comment: can i set length limit like this                                                               RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]{1-15})$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L] –

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - Yes, that would work. You probably want to just do a quick read-through on how regular expressions work. I recommend checking out [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), they'll give  good overview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89388/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-eykanal).